# parseFloat(x).toFixe(2) returns a string

Tags: node.js

Can someone explain what is happening under the hood and how can i get the expected result? I am trying to convert some string and add them eg. '1.7888884448', '2.359848484' and '3.78333833' to 1.8 , 2.4 and 3.8 
Then do 1.8+2.4+3.8 = 8 . how can i achieve cause :

```
let x = parseFloat('95.568').toFixed(2) + 2 // it's concatenating
console.log (x)
// output 95.572
console.log(typeof x)
// out put 'string'

let y =  parseFloat('95.568') + 2 
console.log (y)
// output 97.568
console.log(typeof y)
// out put 'number'
```

Comment: This is correct behavior because `.toFixed()` is documented to return a string, see [mdn .toFixed() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: An easier workaround for this is preceding your call to `toFixed` with a + sign. `+someNumber.toFixed(decimalPlaces)` returns a number

Comment: Of course, its a base-2 floating point number (https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type). You can't properly represent the number with two base-10 decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can first add them and then achieve accuracy to 2 decimal points. The result will be more accurate.

```
function addDecimalStrings(decimalStringArr) {
    let sum = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<decimalStringArr.length; i++){
        // Parse and add
        sum = sum + parseFloat(decimalStringArr[i]);
    }

    // Convert to two decimal points
    return sum.toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply put another parseFloat around, it will keep the decimal number :

```
parseFloat(parseFloat("9.55656").toFixed(2))

9.56
```

Comment: parseFloat(parseFloat("9").toFixed(2))

In this case it will give just 9

Answer (score 1):

The required solution can be obtained by

```
(Math.round( '1.7888884448' * 10 ) + Math.round( '2.359848484' * 10 ) + Math.round( '3.78333833' * 10 ))/10
```

Now regarding the code :

`parseFloat('95.568').toFixed(2)` returns a string, and `string + integer` in javascript converts the integer to string and appends it.

`let x = Number(parseFloat('95.568').toFixed(2)) + 2` will give an integer